# how can i include a file via a variables value

Tags: nim-lang

I want to set a variable to the file path to include and then use that variable to include it
I tried:

```
var path: string = "example.nim"
include path
```

This gives an error because it thinks the path I'm trying to include is "path"
Basically I want to include "example.nim" when set to a variable value

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to `include` file at runtime (like you can in python) because nim is a statically compiled language. You can, however write a macro that generates necessary `include` statement (though I would really advise against that unless you have very specific use case that requires such code):

```
import std/macros

macro makeIncludeStrLit(
  arg: static[string]): untyped =
  # ^ To pass value to macro use `static[<your-type>]`

  newTree(nnkIncludeStmt, newLit(arg))
  # Generates `include "your string"`

static:
  writeFile("/tmp/something.nim", "echo 123")

const path = "/tmp/something.nim"
# ^ path MUST be known at compile-time in order for macro to work.

makeIncludeStrLit(path)
```